# Metro style app media capture exception

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm writing my first metro-style app. Days ago I've written the code for taking photos based on this sample ([here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622)) and it works. With the release of Windows 8 release preview and visual studio 2012 release candidate, the same snippet doesn't work. It seems that there is a problem with the access to camera but in Package.appxmanifest I've checked the webcam capability.
**the xaml :**

```
<Canvas x:Name="previewCanvas1" Width="320"  Height="240" Background='Gray'>
<Image x:Name="imageElement1"  Width="320" Height="240" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<CaptureElement x:Name="previewElement1" Width="320" Height="240" />
</Canvas>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
 <Button Width="120" x:Name="btnStartPreview2" Click="btnStartPreview_Click" IsEnabled="true"  Margin="0,0,10,0"  Background="#FFC3C3C3">Da Webcam</Button>
<Button Width="120" x:Name="btnTakePhoto2" Click="btnTakePhoto_Click" IsEnabled="false"  Margin="0,0,10,0"  Background="#FFC3C3C3">Scatta</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**And the code behind:**

```
MediaCapture mediaCaptureMgr;
async void btnStartPreview_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                mediaCaptureMgr = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
                await mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync();

                previewElement1.Source = mediaCaptureMgr;

                await mediaCaptureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

the exception is: "**Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**" but as said, the webcam capability is checked!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it. To use the webcam you must indicate in package.appxmanifest that the application needs to access the webcam and **microphone**. Strange but true!

Comment: You can set the MediaCapture class to just capture video when calling InitializeAsync(); That being said, I've been getting all these crazy unknown errors too, presumably for different reasons.

Comment: Even after checking Microphone, I gets the same error.